# knockout js - check if property exists

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to render the following with knockout.

```
<!-- ko with: address-->
<!-- ko if: address1-->
<span style="display : block">
<span data-bind="varchar : address1"></span>
</span>
<span style="display : block">
<span data-bind="varchar : address2"></span>
</span>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

The problem is that even if the address object is present it may not contain the address1 parameter.
I'd like knockout to not render the nested spans if the parameter 'address1' is null.
Currently the following error is thrown:

```
Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: address1 is not defined;
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: On further testing the code above actually works. Must have been a ghost in the machine.

Comment: There is a difference between undefined and null.  Your original question indicates that `address1` was undefined.  Now, it appears that you have `address1` defined, but its value is null.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Isn't it just a case of moving your second if?

```
<!-- ko with: address -->
<span style="display : block">
<!-- ko if: address1 -->
<span data-bind="varchar : address1"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
</span>
<span style="display : block">
<span data-bind="varchar : address2"></span>
</span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Looks like we need to see your viewModel and how addresses relate to each other. I can do that on the sample from knockout page with no problems:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: city"> </h1>
<p data-bind="with: coords">
    <!-- ko if: latitude -->
    Latitude: <span data-bind="text: latitude"> </span>,
    <!-- /ko -->
    Longitude: <span data-bind="text: longitude"> </span>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm just checking for address1 as the others will also be null if address1 is.

Answer (score 97):

If you use `<!-- ko if: $data.address1 -->`, then it will not error out if `address1` is undefined.

If `address1` does later become populated, it will not update the UI though (`address1` would need to be an observable originally).

Comment: Upvoted because it's very important that address1 is an observable if the UI is intended to be updated

Comment: seems like <!- ko if: $data.address1 --> is missing a "-", correct is <!-- ko if: $data.address1 -->

Comment: Can anyone explain why `<!-- ko if: address1 -->` does not suffice and generates errors  if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 7):

I had a case where I had an address template being called from different places.

My 'country name' data field was sometimes `countryName` and sometimes `countryDesc`.

I just changed the template to this:

```
 <div data-bind="text: $data.countryName || $data.countryDesc"></div>
```

This takes advantage of the fact that if you use `$data` it won't error out (as pointed out by RP Niemeyer)

Comment: Forget the `<!-- ko: if: -->` answer, *this* should be the answer.  Simple, clean, and most importantly it lets you set a value when the variable doesn't exist (unlike the `if` which only lets you not show anything if the variable doesn't exist).

Comment: This isn't really a good general answer if you expect it to ever be empty (because it will leave an empty <div></div> which is quite clumsy). I since learnt about the `:empty` css selector which can be used to hide the div if empty so that's a bit more or less hacky depending upon how you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this behavior could be the initial data of your "address" observable.

If you are initializing your viewmodel this way:

```
this.address = ko.observableArray();
```

then both "address" and "address1" are undefined.

A workaround would be check the data at the beginning of the block by wrapping the code into a "ko if" statement, this way:

```
<!-- ko if: $data --> <br/>
<br/>
<span style="display : block"><br/>
<span data-bind="varchar : address1"></span><br/>
</span><br/>
<span style="display : block"><br/>
<span data-bind="varchar : address2"></span><br/>
</span><br/>
<br/>
<!-- /ko -->
```